# Approximate $\int_0^{\pi /2} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{1-x\sin^2s}}$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I am trying to approximate the following integral 
$$K(x)=\int\limits_0^{\pi /2} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{1-x\sin^2s}}$$
with $0<x<1$.
I need to show that for x close to one that $K(x)\sim -\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-x)$.

My first attempt was to Taylor expand the function $f(x)= (1-x\sin^2s)^{-1/2}$ about $x=1$. I did this using $f(x)\approx f(1)+f'(1)(x-1)$. I integrated the result and found that $K(x)\sim \left[\frac{5-x}{4}\ln|\sec s + \tan s|\right]_0^{\pi/2} - \left[\frac{1-x}{4}\sec s \tan s \right]_0^{\pi/2}$, which goes to infinity when $s=\pi/2$.

I can't think of another way to approach this, so any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Are you using $K(x)$ to refer to integral you are trying to approximate? That's probably a poor choice since the integral has an exact closed form representation in terms of the complete elliptic integral of the 1st kind, a.k.a. $K(x)$.

Comment: $K(x)$ refers to the elliptical integral, yes. That comes from the problem description.

Comment: Heh, my confusion was that the exact form of the integral can be written in terms of the elliptic integral as $ \frac{K(\frac{x}{x-1})}{\sqrt{1-x}} $, making $K$ a bad name for the function defined by the integral unless the identity $K(x) = \frac{K(\frac{x}{x-1})}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ happens to be true. ...And it happens to be true, so, shows what I know, eh? =)

Comment: The identity is true by [Landen's transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landen%27s_transformation).

$$K(x) 
= \frac{\pi}{2\text{AGM}(1,\sqrt{1-x})} 
= \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1-x}\text{AGM}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}},1)}\\ 
= \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1-x}\text{AGM}(\sqrt{1-\frac{x}{x-1}},1)} 
= \frac{K(\frac{x}{x-1})}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral as written is the 
[complete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) and it can be expressed in term of [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function):

$$K(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}\,_2F_1(\frac12,\frac12;1;x)\tag{*1}$$

We know when $\gamma = \alpha + \beta$, $\alpha$ and $\beta \ne 0, -1, -2, \ldots$, $|\arg(1-x)| < \pi$, $|1-x| < 1$, the hypergeometric function has following 
expansion near $x = 1$:

$$\begin{align}
\,_2F_1(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;x) = 
& \frac{-\Gamma(\gamma)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\alpha)_n(\beta)_n}{n!^2}(1-x)^n \times\\
& \left\{
\psi(\alpha+n)+\psi(\beta+n) -2\psi(1+n) + \log(1-x)
\right\}
\end{align}$$
where $(t)_n$ is the rising [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) and $\psi(t)$ is the 
[digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Substitute this back into $(*1)$ for $x$ near $1$, we have up to $O((1-x)\log(1-x))$,

$$K(x) \sim -\frac12 \left\{ 2\psi(\frac{1}{2}) - 2\psi(1) + \log(1-x)\right\}
          = \log 4 - \frac12\log(1-x)$$

Actually, we can derive this leading term by elementary means.
Let $\delta = \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}$, $u = \cos s = \delta \sinh\theta$, we have

$$\begin{align}
K(x) 
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{\delta^2 + \cos^2\!s}}\\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\int_0^1 \frac{du}{\sqrt{\delta^2 + u^2}\sqrt{1-u^2}}\\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left\{
\int_0^1  \frac{du}{\sqrt{\delta^2 + u^2}} + 
\int_0^1 \frac{1-\sqrt{1-u^2}}{\sqrt{\delta^2+u^2}} \frac{du}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}
\right\}\\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left\{
\int_0^1 \frac{du}{\sqrt{\delta^2 + u^2}} +
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1-\sin s}{\sqrt{\delta^2 + \cos^2\!s}} ds
\right\}\\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left\{
\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}\frac{1}{\delta}} d\theta +
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1-\sin s}{\sqrt{\delta^2 + \cos^2\!s}} ds
\right\}\\
\end{align}$$
The $2^{nd}$ integral in the RHS has a finite limit as $\delta \to 0$. 
If we replace it by its limit, we will introduce an error that won't affect
our determination of the leading term. Up to $o(1)$$\color{blue}{^{[1]}}$, we find:
$$\begin{align}
K(x) 
\sim & \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left\{\sinh^{-1}\frac{1}{\delta} + \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1-\sin s}{\cos s} ds
\right\}\\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left\{ \log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+\delta^2}}{\delta}\right) + \log 2\right\}\\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left\{ \log\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\right) + \log 2\right\}\\
\sim & (1 + O(1-x))
\left\{\log\left(\frac{1 + O(1-x) + 1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\right) + \log 2\right\}\\
\sim & \log 4 - \frac12\log(1-x) + O((1-x)\log(1-x))
\end{align}$$
recovering the leading term as expected.

***Notes***

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ A more careful analysis shows the error introduced in this step is of the order $O(\delta^2\log\delta) = O((1-x)\log(1-x))$.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about where the $\sqrt{x}$ contributions go in the next-to-last line?

Comment: I have been analyzing this for a while now and I have a few 
questions.First, I don' t quite understand how you separated the this term $\frac {1} {\sqrt {x}}\int_ 0^1\frac {du} {\sqrt {\delta^2 + u^2}\sqrt {1 - u^2}} $ into the following two terms. Second, is it ok for you to say that $\delta \to 0$ but not apply it to both terms that contain $\delta$. Finally, how did you get the $\sinh^{-1}$ after integrating? I can get the result in the next line, but I am just curious how you found a your result.

Comment: Also, could you also give me a bit of insight as to what made you choose the $\delta$ in the first place? The first solution sounds interesting as I have never heard of a hypergeometric function. The second solution is something that I might have tried but I don't think I would have picked that $\delta$.

Comment: @rioneye answers updated to clarify some points. The $\delta$ is chosen so that we can introduce the variable substitution $u = \delta\sinh\theta$ and evalute the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{du}{\sqrt{\delta^2+u^2}}$ as $\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}\frac{1}{\delta}} d\theta = \sinh^{-1}\frac{1}{\delta}$.

Comment: One last question, at the end we have a $\ln 4$ term how can we justify that it is negligible? That is how is $K(x)\sim - \frac{1}{2}\ln(1-x)$ equivalent to $K(x)\sim \ln 4 -\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-x)$? Can we say that the second term is much much larger than the first term since $x$ is close to 0, hence the first term drops out ?

Comment: @rioneye It really depends on how small your $x$ will be. If $x$ is really really close to $1$, the term $\log 4$ is of course negligible compared to $-\frac12\log(1-x)$. However, logarithm diverges very slowly. For example, when $1 - x \sim 10^{-6}$, $-\frac12\log(1-x) \sim 6.9077$ and $\log 4 \sim 1.3863$ is a 20% correction of that! In any asymptotic expansion of an integral whose expansion involves logarithms, if you want a reasonable numerical estimate of the integral, you do need the constant term!